# Java command of openjdk doesn't show what class is missing

Tags: java

I am attempting to run a test class that exercises classes in a jar.
It runs fine on my Windows machine where I do my development, but it does not run on a stripped down Ubuntu docker image.

I believe it is failing because it needs some extra classes to run, classes that it cannot find on my test machine.

Using Oracle's jdk on Windows, if there is a missing class that is needed, the java command gives a stack dump and shows the name of the class that is missing.

But using openjdk, it simply says:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.MyTest

Is there someway I can make openjdk's java command show me what the missing class is?

Note that java's -verbose flag does not yield any useful information in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing class is `com.test.MyTest`

This is most likely a problem with the docker configuration. For a java jar to run, it has to choose a main method. Since there are many classes in a jar, there can be many main methods. You typically run a java jar with a command like

```
java -cp <your jar list> com.test.MyTest
```

This command is failing because when the classpath is being searched for the class and it is not being found.

Comment: I was going to tell you how this couldn't be the case and that I verified it was really there, but you are right, I forgot that yesterday I renamed the Test file to NativeT, so that I could control when maven ran it, and I was using the wrong name on the java command line.  So thanks you were right.